# Newbie: set content view which consists of two parts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.1-eclair

I am developing an Android 2.1 app.

I have defined a `LinearLayout` **class**:

```
public class MyTopBar extends LinearLayout {
   ...
}
```

Then, I have a layout xml file (`content.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout>
    ...
</LienarLayout>
```

I have a `RootActivity.java` , I would like to set `MyTopBar` as content in this RootActivity.

Then I have MyActivity which extends `RootActivity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends RootActivity{
       //set xml layout as content here    
}
```

I would like to set the content.xml as content of MyActivity.

As a whole, I would like to use the above way to achieve the layout that `MyTopBar` should be located **on top of** the screen always. The other Activities which extend `RootActivity` will have its content **below** `MyTopBar`. How to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

1 You could add your custom `LinearLayout` directly to the xml layout of the `MyActivity` class like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <com.full.package.MyTopBar 
       attributes here like on any other xml views
    />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

or you could use the `include` tag to include the layout with the custom view:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/xml_file_containing_mytopbar"
    />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

2 Use :

```
setContentView(R.layout.other_content);
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post, please have a look. Basically, i would like to separate MyTopBar from XML layout so that I only initiate MyTopBar in RootActivity, other activities which extends root acitivity only set xml content, as a whole, I want to have the MyTopBar show on top of screen, with other xml layout show below it...

Comment: @Leem.fin I know what you are trying to do, probably a bar across all your activities. Your best bet , i think, is to use the `include` tag and simple include a xml layout which contains only your own custom view. You can't set a `contentView` in `RootActivity` because it will be replaced in the sub classes.

Comment: @Leem.fin Here is a link from google http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a Layout vacant for the TopBar and add Your Topbar in it by using `layout.addView(topbarObject);`
Regarding your second question the setContentView can be called only once, as far as I know. You can however have those two xml files inflated using `View.inflate(other_content.xml)` and added in the parent xml layout whenever you need it. You can `removeView()` on parent layout and `addView()` with the new layout file.

Edit:
For the solution of both the question, you can have a parent Layout for eg. like the following:

```
//Omitting the obvious tags
//parent.xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your code set the parent layout as content view,make an object of your TopBar layout and add it to the topLayout.

```
setContentView(R.layout.parent);
MyTopBar topBar=new MyTopBar(this);
RelativeLayout toplayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewByid(R.id.topLayout);
topLayout.addView(topBar); //or you can directly add it to the parentLayout, but it won't work for the first question. So better stick to it.
```

Now inflate the required xml layout. and add it to contentLayout.

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)View.inflate(R.layout.content,null);
contentLayout.addView(layout);//Assuming you've done the findViewById on this.
```

and when you need to show the other content xml, just call the following code.

```
contentLayout.removeAllView();
RelativeLayout layout2=(RelativeLayout)View.inflate(R.layout.other_content,null);
contentLayout.addView(layout2);
```

Comment: Hi, sounds a good solution, could you please be more specific by code. thank you. (At least the first one, hopefully also the answer for my 2nd question)

Comment: I've updated my answer to have full code, however due to my laziness I've omitted some obvious stuffs in it. I hope you can fill them up.